# How to route a blank page inside Nuxt-js method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my nuxt js project , when user clicked button, method works and it creates a link. I route user to a new page. Sure i want to open this in new target . I could not find any solution for this in nuxt js.

```
   <a :href="`/ticketPrint?${urlLink}`" target="_blank">Go to url</a>
```

if i apply this way, it works in second click because in first click creates link. So i dont wanna use this way . I want to route it inside my method.

```
async printData(){
......
 await this.$router.push(this.urlLink)
}
```

Sure i want to open this in blank page. and i create this new page based url query informations.

Comment: Not sure what `printData` is used for, here.

Comment: it is just method. I get necessary informations and and create a link in this method. when page changed i create a pdf page based url informations

Answer (score 1):

If your page is internal use this way:

```
<template>
  <NuxtLink to="/" target="_blank">Home page</NuxtLink>
</template>
```

If it is an external link:

```
<a href="https://nuxtjs.org" target="_blank">External Link to another page</a>
```

See the [nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/routing) documentation!

I hope it helped you!

Comment: Firstly i create link. If ı dont create link, i cant get any information from my new blank page. So if it routes directly , users will face with empty page .

Comment: Try to create a method that creates and executes it, this method is called in the <a> tag with an on-click

Comment: İ did something like that but target="_blank" routes to new page directly withot waiting route creation

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

```
                let routeData = this.$router.resolve({
                    path: '/getTicketPage',
                    query: {ticketNumber : ticketNumber , orderNumber : orderNumber}
                }); 
 
                window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`nuxt-link`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-nuxtlink-component) here and you can pass it any regular VueJS [`router-link` options](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link) to it.

The `target=_blank` should be fine.

```html
<nuxt-link:to="`/ticketPrint?${urlLink}`">Home page</nuxt-link>
```

Comment: When user clicked route button firstly i need to create link inside my method after some process and it takes time sure. in this way , user gonna go to empty page . Because i will take information by using route query . So ı neeed to route it inside my method

Comment: Not sure I get what you're looking at here. But you may write a `button` tag and give it a `@click="printData"`, which then redirects the user to the generated page.